# Create my own limited linkedlist based on java.util.linkedlist

Tags: java, class, collections, constructor, linked-list

I want to do something simple which is create my own list class that is based on java.util.linkedlist but i want to limit what can be done. Lets just say that for now, the only method I want available is the addFirst method. I'm creating somewhat of a singly linked list. The issue i'm having is that addFirst doesnt seem to be recognized and i'm not sure if i'm creating the list properly inside my own constructor. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class singleList {

singleList() {
     new LinkedList();
 }

//  void add(name addName) {
//      addFirst(addName);
//  }


public static void main(String[] args) {

singleList nameList = new singleList();

 name name1 = new name("John", "Smith");
 nameList.add(name1);


System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList);

 }
}
```

So as you can see what I want to do is create a list called nameList and at this point, the ONLY thing it can do is use the add method, which should call the LinkedList's addFirst method which adds the element to the first position in the list. Does this make sense?

The first error I get is that it cannot find the symbol "addFirst" from my add method and i'm also not sure if my constructor for singleList is correct.

### In case anyone is wondering, this is for a school assignment.

Here is the revised code, which I took some advise from the first answer here which looks similiar to another.

```
public class SingleList {

private LinkedList internalList;

SingleList() {
     internalList = new LinkedList();
 }

void add(name addName) {
    internalList.addFirst(addName);
}

String get(int index) {

    return internalList.get(index).toString();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    SingleList nameList = new SingleList();

    name name1 = new name("John", "Smith");
    nameList.add(name1);

    String getter = nameList.get(0);  
    System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList.get(0));

}
}
```

Comment: Do you want your "singleList" to *inherit* from java.util.LinkedList?  Then you'll need to say "extends".  ALSO: good practice would be to name your class "SingleList" (and instances you create of that class could be named "singleList").

Comment: Extends works but then it allows direct access to any of the linkedList implementations and I dont want that. For example, I dont want the ability to add to the back of the list using addLast. I will modify the naming of my singleList to SingleList. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that you aren't assigning the `LinkedList` to anything, then the `addFirst()` method is written as if it's a static method of the `singleList` class, which doesn't exist. What I believe you were trying to do is:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SingleList<T>
{
    private LinkedList<T> internal;

    SingleList()
    {
        this.internal = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void add(T addName)
    {
        this.internal.addFirst(addName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(!this.internal.isEmpty())
        {
            return this.internal.get(0).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.internal.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SingleList<name> nameList = new SingleList<>();
        name name1 = new name("John", "Smith");
        nameList.add(name1);
        System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList);
    }
}
```

This also has the benefit of generics, which means it can use any type which `LinkedList` can use. Additionally, I took the liberty of changing the case of the class name, as the Java standard is to use proper cases on Class names, and sulking case on variables.

Comment: After reading the other answer below, i took some of the code and modified my original code. It looks similiar to what you have posted here and it seems to work without any issues so far. Although I didnt use generics in it which I dont think I need but i do see how that would be a benefit. I will post my new code somewhere here but not sure where it will show up.

Answer (score 2):

your class should implement List interface and redirect its methods to the linked list:

```
public class singleList implements List {
    private LinkedList internalList;

    public singleList() {
        internalList = new LinkedList();
    }
    public boolean add(Object e) {
        return internalList.add(e);
    }

    public remove(Object o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented.");
    }

    ...
}
```

for the methods that you want limited simply throw an exception.

Comment: There must be an easier way then writing exception codes for every method I dont want access to. I do appreciate the help but I hope theres another way.

Comment: A class should **not** extend List unless it is intended to implement all non-optional methods of List, which does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this make sense?

Not that much. But well, to test around you do not need it.

> The first error I get is that it cannot find the symbol "addFirst" from my add method and i'm also not sure if my constructor for singleList is correct.

You named it add, not addFirst.
The constructor is not ok.
The method and constructor could look like this:

```
public class singleList {
    private LinkedList<name> listName = new LinkedList<>();

    void addFirst(name addName) {
        listName.addFirst(addName);
    }
}
```

As you notice, there is no constructor anymore. This is because java automatically adds a default constructor:

```
public singleList() {
}
```

Then, I have added a private class variable, which is what you need to access the list.

```
System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList);
```

---

This will not work, your singlelist and name classes have to implement toString, for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return listName.toString();
}
```

(name class has to implement toString, too)

---

Some further hints:

Try to use the standard java naming convention. Like uppercase names for classes:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

    public Name(String firstName, String secondName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [firstName=" + firstName + ", secondName=" + secondName + "]";
    }
}

public class SingleList { //should have a better name perhaps

    private LinkedList<Name> listName = new LinkedList<>();

    public SingleList() {
    }

    void addFirst(Name name) {
        listName.addFirst(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return listName.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleList listName = new SingleList();

        Name newName = new Name("John", "Smith");
        listName.addFirst(newName);

        System.out.println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList);
    }
}
```

Try to continue from this point, I am sure you have more to do.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start ...

- Unless your class either `extends` the `LinkedList` class (or some other `List` class) or `implements` the `List` interface, it won't be a `List`.
- If your class is not a `List`, then it won't have an `addFirst` method (unless you defined one).  That's why you can't call the `addFirst` method in your `add` method!
- Your constructor is creating a `LinkedList` instance ... and then throwing it away.  That is pointless.  I suspect you should be assigning it to ... something.  (Hint)
- The statement `println("LinkedList contains : " + nameList)` will call the `toString()` method on the `nameList` object to turn it into a String.  Since you've created a class that doesn't extend an existing `List` class you need to override the `toString` provided by `Object` ... 'cos *that* version won't display the contents of your list!

There are two approaches you could be using here.  You could be creating a class that overrides the behaviour of a parent (`List`) class, or you could be creating a "wrapper" class that has a real `List` class inside it.  You are doing neither.

A wrapper class is probably going to solve your immediate needs more simply ... *assuming* that you don't need a true `List` class.  The other approach would require you to override *every* method that you want to prevent to have it throw an exception (typically, [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) ...) doing that for all operations in the `LinkedList` API would be tedious.

Finally, while I have your attention, Java class names should **ALWAYS** start with a capital letter.

Comment: I'm trying to post my revised code but it just shows up as all text. Not sure how to post it properly.